# String to double in android gives wrong value

Tags: android, string, double

So I have this piece of code:

```
String tmp_s = sampleTime.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""); // after this 20131218125600
tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(4); // after this 1218125600
tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(0, tmp_s.length()-2); // after this 12181256
double d = Double.parseDouble(tmp_s); // after this 1.2161256E12??????????????
```

I am clueless, why do I have a double that is 1.2161256E12 and not 12161256.0??

And where does the letter E come from?

Comment: Ok, didnt know it was represented like that.

Thing is I am plotting things into a chart, this number are going to be on the X-axis(its a date), the chart takes in two doubles for each point.

The first part was just to test thing how far away the chart were going to plot the numbers, using the year and milliseconds seemed to be to much information that is not interesting.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation -- scroll down to E-notation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Comment: @blackbelt : 7 != 12, mind you.

Comment: @blackbelt 1.2161256E12 is not the same as 12161256.0 but 1216125600000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
        String sampleTime = "20131218125600";
        String tmp_s = sampleTime.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""); // after this 20131218125600
        tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(4); // after this 1218125600
        tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(0, tmp_s.length()-2); // after this 12181256
        double d = Double.parseDouble(tmp_s); 
        Log.v("d", ""+d);

        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        try {
            Number num = dF.parse(tmp_s);
            Log.v("num", ""+num);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

yes `1.2161256E7` and `12161256.0` are same like this `1.2161256*10000000` and also like `1.2161256*10^7`

Answer (score 1):

double is used to represent floating value that is either too small or big. And the value you are getting too small and its into exponential form.

Answer (score 1):

i have some changes in your code . //1.2181256E7
That showing perfect value ans:1.2181256E7 check this below code..

```
        String sampleTime="20131218125600";   
        String tmp_s = sampleTime.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(4); // after this 1218125600
        tmp_s = tmp_s.substring(0, tmp_s.length()-2); // after this 12181256
       //2. Use valueOf method of Double class. This method is static.
        Double dObj2 = Double.valueOf(tmp_s);
        System.out.println(dObj2);
```